# Can an android app read its own apk file?

Tags: android, apk

Would like the app to check the (keyed) message digest of the apk file that is currently running.

I can do this with java applications running from a jar file.

Need to read the apk into the app, from there it's easy.

Not sure it's feasible in Android.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but highly discouraged, since Play can modify the APKs for security purposes (see https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html?m=1) so the APK installed on your users' devices is unlikely to have the same digest as the one you upload to the Play Console.

You should instead rely on the signature of the APK or at the very least on the digest of each file rather than the APK as a whole.

That being said, to answer your question, you can request the `ApplicationInfo` from the `PackageManager` then read the [`sourceDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#sourceDir) attribute which will give you the installation path of the base APK. With split APKs, the APKs would instead be installed in `splitSourceDirs` (but unless you publish an Android App Bundle, you probably don't need to worry about this).

Hope that helps,

Comment: Thanks, I suspected that the Play Store was adding something.